# replace a vector of pattern with another vector in R

Tags: regex, r, string, replace

I have a situation like this,

```r
a <- c("abc", "bcd", "def")
b <- c("pqr", "rat", "xyz")
c <- c("abc", "def", "abc", "bcd", "bcd", "abc", "def", "abc", "bcd")
```

I want a vector `d` (say) with each `c` replaced by values in `b` that matches `a`. In shortcut, I need this vector,

```
"pqr" "xyz" "pqr" "rat" "rat" "pqr" "xyz" "pqr" "rat"
```

I can do `gsub` by searching each individual string, but how can I do with all of them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
d <- b[match(c,a)]

# [1] "pqr" "xyz" "pqr" "rat" "rat" "pqr" "xyz" "pqr" "rat"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying with converting into factor and replacing its labels. But this is clean.